# Customize Spellcheck Highlight Colour in RStudio

Tags: rstudio, themes

I'm using RStudio 1.3 and its spellchecker, but I find that the highlight colour for misspelled words is hard to see.
I’m trying to change it in the rstheme file to make it more visible, in particular for the Tomorrow Night Bright theme.

I tried searching for a solution and looked into the rstheme file, but I can’t understand how to do it.
Is it possible to customize this and how?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would contact the Rstudio team by filing a GH issue, or by posting a question at community.rstudio.com.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I already tried with the community forum, but got no answer, I'll try on GH.